# mysql_connect('mysite.com', 'root', ' '); not working

Tags: php, server, mysql-connect

I have spent my few hours on finding out why 
     **mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');** 
works fine on localhost 
but

```
mysql_connect('mysite.com', 'root', ''');
```

does not works on the server ,

can anyone please help !!!

Comment: try also with `localhost` on your server as host!

Comment: are you sure the 3 single quotes? you must escape it

Comment: whats your server version

Comment: Since you run `mysql_connect` in your server, you can write `localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use mysql methods it is deprecated.

You can use PDO or mysqli

PDO as:

```
try{
   $username = 'root';
   $dbname = 'mysql:host=mysite.com';
   $password = 'password';
   $conn = new PDO($dbname, $username, $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   // do things here
}
catch(Exception $e){
   //error
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some checklist in my mind right now:

1.use

> ```
> ini_set('display_errors',1);
> ```

or check the php error log to see if there is anything wrong.

2.try to connect to your MySQL server using a console such as sqlyog or any other consoles with user/password you use in your php code.

3.check if the srever that runs php codes have access to MySQL server.

Answer (score -1):

**Warning**

**This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:**

So use
 - [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)
 - [PDO::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: yes if user server is above PHP 5.5.0, and api will reject if you still have problem read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Am 100% sure user server will be more that PHP 5.5.0

Comment: @Gunaseelan every server will be up-to-date and this is why he get error

Comment: @Gunaseelan every server will be up-to-date check out Gourab Nag answer and i think you have to read about server hosting site if a server is out of date user will stop using that hosting site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68118/discussion-between-gunaseelan-and-sanoj-lawrence).